# How long does it take for a curve too reach a specific x coordinate?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, numerical-integration

How do I calculate the time it takes for a curve to reach a specific `x` coordinate (in Matlab). Let's say we have:
dx/dt = x^2 + y^2 and dy/dt = 5.x.y and the curve starts at the point (a,b). With help from `ode45` I was able to get the figure of the curve. I need too calculate the time it takes for the curve too reach x = c, (c>a). I've been told that this can be done by interpolation, but I have no idea how to write the code.

Comment: have you looked at [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html)?

Comment: yes but to be honest, i didn't quit get what i supposed to write as a code.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the behavior of your system around `c`, using data interpolation methods such as `interp1` on the output may or may not work. The more rigorous way to solve this is either with events (see my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15992197/2278029) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16639006/2278029)) or by using the single structure output argument form of `ode45` in conjunction with [`deval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deval.html) and regular data interpolation methods. Both of these use [polynomial interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) methods designed to work with the underlying ODEs. Though more complicated, events are probably the best way to accuratly determine crossing times like your case.